# Calling Excluding method in extension method for FluentAssertions.Primitives.ObjectAssertions does not work, but calling it normally works

Tags: c#, nunit, integration-testing, extension-methods, fluent-assertions

I have started using `FluentAssertions` library in my integration tests for the REST endpoints. The problem is I have to compare two entities, but excluding their `_id` properties. This property is being inherited from my `IEntity` interface.

```
public interface IEntity
{
    [BsonId]
    ObjectId _id { get; set; }
}
```

So for example `Log` class looks like this

```
[DataContract]
public class Log : IEntity
{
    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId _id { get; set; }

    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

In the test I am comparing them like this and it works

```
retrieved.Should()
         .BeEquivalentTo(expected, options => options.Excluding(member => member._id));
```

But when I extract this functionality to extension method for reuse purposes, it does not work. It does not ignore the `_id` member.

```
public static class ObjectAssertionExtensions
{
    public static void BeEquivalentToExcludingId<TExpectation>(this ObjectAssertions objectAssertion, TExpectation expectation) where TExpectation : IEntity
    {
        objectAssertion.BeEquivalentTo(expectation, options => options.Excluding(member => member._id));
    }
}
```

When I change the generic extension method to a specific type `Log`, then it works like it should.
I have prepared minimal project with example [here](http://www.filedropper.com/genericextensionmethodnotworking).
Is there a way how to get this working please and why does it not work properly? I will try to check the code of `FluentAssertions` in github repository. Thanks.

Comment: Does it make any difference if you cast `expected` to `IEntity` before using it in `BeEquivalentTo`?

Comment: No, it gives me "Message: System.InvalidOperationException : No members were found for comparison. Please specify some members to include in the comparison or choose a more meaningful assertion."

Comment: It could be a case of https://github.com/fluentassertions/fluentassertions/issues/1077. It's fixed in master but hasn't been released yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that Fluent Assertions fails to correlate `_id` of the generic type `T` to `_id` of the concrete type `Log`.

A similar issue was reported in [#1077](https://github.com/fluentassertions/fluentassertions/issues/1077) and resolved with [#1087](https://github.com/fluentassertions/fluentassertions/pull/1087). 
As of writing we haven't released new version containing this fix.

**Edit 2019-08-10:**

Fluent Assertions 5.8.0 has been released with the fix.

Comment: Thanks, I am looking forward to the new release then :).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, in `ObjectAssertionsExtensions` it makes sense to change

```
public static void BeEquivalentToExcludingId<TExpectation>(this ObjectAssertions objectAssertion,
    TExpectation expectation) where TExpectation : IEntity
```

to

```
public static void BeEquivalentToExcludingId(this ObjectAssertions objectAssertion,
    IEntity expectation)
```

I'd also put each assertion into separate test to localize the problem.

The thing happens because `BeEquivalentToExcludingId` expects `IEntity` with `_id` property only, but gets `Log` with extra `Message` property. That makes everything go wrong. If it doesn't harm your architecture just ammend `IEntity` with `string Message` property and it will fix the thing. So, the only change:

```
public interface IEntity
{
    [BsonId]
    ObjectId _id { get; set; }

    string Message { get; set; }
}
```

solves the problem.

**Update:**

Taking into account your comment, just set members to exclude to the same value, call `BeEquivalentTo` and set actual values back like this:

```
public static void BeEquivalentToExcludingId(this ObjectAssertions objectAssertion, IEntity expectation)
{
    var subj = (IEntity)objectAssertion.Subject;
    var subjId = subj._id;
    var expId = expectation._id;

    subj._id = ObjectId.Empty;
    expectation._id = ObjectId.Empty;

    objectAssertion.BeEquivalentTo(expectation);

    subj._id = subjId;
    expectation._id = expId;
}
```

It's hacky, but it works.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out better extension method definition by directly using the type IEntity. However, adding the Message and all the other properties into IEntity defies its purpose and I would end up with just one class containing all the properties of the descendant classes. So this is not a viable solution.

Comment: @c0ntrol, you are welcome. But I believe it could be neater.